# processing JSON file using jq in bash

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have the following bash script

```
counter=0
for file in /home/ec2-user/Workspace/events_parts/*
do
        counter=$[counter + 1]
        event=$(cat $file | jq '.Event')
        echo $event
        if [ "$event" = "Page Exceeded" ]  || [ "$event" = "Reporting Time" ]; then
                echo "Coming Here"
                jq ".url = \"$(jq '.Message' $file | sed 's/.*proxy=\([^&]*\).*/\1/')\"" $file  > events_parts/out_$file
        else
                jq ".url = null" $file > events_parts/out_$file
        fi
done
```

It does processing of a set of JSON files.I want to redirect it to a filename which has out_$input_file_name. But the variable file prints out the whole path not just the file name (for e.g. `/home/ec2-user/Workspace/events_parts/input.json`) How do I get just the "input file name" from this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [processing a JSON file usign jq in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29111997/processing-a-json-file-usign-jq-in-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
file="/home/ec2-user/Workspace/events_parts/input.json"
filename="$(basename "$file")"
echo "$filename"
```

Output:

```
input.json
```